# Console 2 command aliases

Tags: alias, console2

I use [Console 2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console) and I would like to create some aliases for commands I use often. Maybe my google-fu just sucks today but I cannot figure out how to do this. Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: change the shell in console2 to powershell. It is much more powerful that the cmd shell.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Console2 is only a wrapper around hidden Win32 console windows and does not provide extended line editing functionality.

You can create aliases in Win32 consoles:

```
doskey d=dir $*
```

Unlike Unix `sh`, you have to explicitly specify `$*` to append given arguments (ex. `d C:\`). You can also use `$T` to separate commands.

Also unlike Unix, aliases are implemented [at Win32 console level](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682057%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), *not* in Console2 or the cmd.exe shell. This also means that you can use them in *any* program that reads interactive input. (For example, `doskey /exename=python.exe h=help($*)` would translate `h sys` to `help(sys)`.)

---

To load the aliases automatically for cmd.exe (Command Prompt):

1. create a batch script (for example, `%APPDATA%\autorun.cmd`) with the `doskey` commands. Example:

   ```
   @doskey d=dir $*
   ```

   Example to read multiple aliases from a file:

   ```
   @doskey /macrofile=%APPDATA%\cmd.aliases
   ```
2. set the `HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor` value `AutoRun` to the path of your "autorun" script:

   ```
   C:\> reg add "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v AutoRun /t REG_SZ /d "%APPDATA%\autorun.cmd"
   ```

Answer (score 13):

Although this question is over a year old and already answered, the following solution is simpler and avoids editing the registry:

In Console2, go to Edit > Settings. Change the "Shell:" field to the following:

```
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /K "C:\Path\to\aliases.cmd"
```

Now restart Console2 and you're done.

To possibly save you some time, here's a simple example of an aliases.cmd file:

```
@echo off

DOSKEY clear=cls
DOSKEY ls=dir
DOSKEY ex=explorer .
DOSKEY ll=dir /A
DOSKEY rm=del $*
```